# How to check characters from string but starting from 4th character to 7th character?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

For Example if i have NSString *a = "com42FA";
How to check the a string contains number, hexadecimal or numerical digits but checking starts from character 4 to chartacter 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution is regular expression

The pattern searches for 4 characters in the character sets `0-9`, `A-F` and `a-f`.

The explicit range `NSMakeRange(3, 4)` searches for character 4 - 7 (the `location` parameter is zero-based).

```
NSString *a = @"com42FA";
NSString *pattern = @"[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:a  options:0 range:NSMakeRange(3, 4)];
BOOL hexNumberFound = range.location != NSNotFound;

NSLog(@"%d", hexNumberFound);
```

Comment: Thanks alot vadian :)

Answer (score 2):

As a third alternative (at the time of writing anyway!) a simple loop will handle this:

```
NSString *testString = @"com42FA";
NSCharacterSet *hexDigits = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789abcdefABCDEF"];

NSUInteger pos = 3;
BOOL isValid = YES;
while (pos <= 6 && isValid) isValid = [hexDigits characterIsMember:[testString characterAtIndex:pos++]];
```

Justs loops and checks stopping as soon as an invalid digit is found.

**Addendum**

As other answers have raised the issue of performance, not that for such a small task it is likely to be an issue, I offer the following faster variation:

```
NSString *testString = @"com42FA";

NSUInteger pos = 3;
BOOL isValid = YES;
while (pos <= 6 && isValid) isValid = isxdigit([testString characterAtIndex:pos++]);
```

This uses the standard C-library function `isxdigit()`, avoiding the need for the `NSCharacterSet` creation and method calls. *(This may not be the fastest option either but readability will probably suffer after this point.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSScanner` which is faster than regular expression for almost all cases:

```objc
NSString *initialString = @"com42FA";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:initialString];

// Setup the scanner. Depends on your needs
scanner.caseSensitive = NO;
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil;

// Specify the location to start scan from
scanner.scanLocation = 3;

// Actual scanning, note that I'm checking that the scanner at the end
// to understand whether it scanned up to the end of the string
unsigned long long scannedNumber = 0;
BOOL success = [scanner scanHexLongLong:&scannedNumber] && scanner.isAtEnd;

if (success) {
  NSLog(@"%llu", scannedNumber); // 17146
  <...>
}
```

Comment: Do you have you any references that `NSScanner` is faster than regex? I doubt that especially for more complicated patterns and for this case where the range to check is given.

Comment: @vadian Sure it depends on a problem we're trying to solve. In general I'd say that the simplest solution to understand and read(regex) will win unless we're really concerned about performance. And addressing your question, it's simple as running regex and scanner examples about 3000000 times. On my machine regex[29 sec] vs scanner[1 sec].

Comment: @vadian: dimv is correct the RE version is slowest, which makes sense given the generality of REs - the other versions are more specialised. The `NSScanner` & `while`/`NSCharacterSet` versions are close - initially the latter beats the former but increasing iterations appears to reverse this. If speed is the issue change drop the `NSCharacterSet` and do `while`/`isxdigit()` and that beats all of them easily. I considered using `isxdigit()` oriignally but decided to avoid introducing a C function, not thinking it was race ;-)